# CATransition displays animation out of the desired view

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using a CATranstion animation to move between multiple HTML pages in a UIWebView.

```
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlPage baseURL:nil];
            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
            [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
            [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
            [animation setSpeed:0.3];
            [[WebView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

The Web view is not displayed in the totality of the iOS device screen, it is displayed in the middle of it. The problem is that when the transition is performed, the text is displayed out of the web view, what I want is that the animation doesn't go out of the web view.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way how CATransition works.

I recommend you add the UIWebView as a subview of some container view and set `clipsToBounds = YES` for the container view. It should work then just like you want.

Try something like this:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 200)];
containerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
_webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[containerView addSubview:_webView];
```

Your transition code is OK and this should do what you want

Simplified explanation of what is happening: Transition makes "bitmap screenshot" of the layer before and after the animation. Then just makes the animation. In your case, it gets 2 bitmaps, puts the new one on the left of the old one and then it "pushes" the old off to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to animate the content inside your web view only. If that's the case, you'd be better off using JS and CSS animations, rather than using Core Animation. Currently you're manipulating the entire `UIWebView`, and the API doesn't give you access to its content outside of the DOM.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, I want the animation only inside the UIWebView, I don't like the text to appear outside it. I don't know how to do it using JavaScript, but to be clearer, the animation is to switch between two html pages, is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found is to add two dummy views with clear background to hide the text that is displayed outside the web view